# Is there any way to use django adminsite in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Currently,I am using Django Rest Framework to develop an API for a project. As we know, Django has default administration but i am wondering how can i convert into DRF or should i write from scratch and later integrate with react?

Seeking better suggestion and some resources cause i am very much new to Django and DRF as well.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have a look on this https://pypi.org/project/django-restful-admin/

Comment: I have looked it already but i feel like its not proper solution in my case. Thanks anyway. I can use `ModelViewSet` instead of using this package. It does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The admin in enabled in default project template. If you don't want to use the default project template please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/

You can customize admin site according to your requirement. Better to customize it and later you can use react for other features. It will help you maintain the code and ease in the code base.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks @Gajanan. I am planning to customize in term of my requirements